# Bean methods are executed even if the Bean methods are not called

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a question:

I have a xhtml page named `LeaveCalenderYearly.xhtml` and its Bean is called `calenderBean` and the said bean has many methods that are used in this xhtml pages.

Now I have three buttons in this page say `button1`,`button2`,`button3`. Each of the buttons opens a Popup and I have written three individual Beans say `bean1`,`bean2` and `bean3` for these three popups and their internal executions.

But whenever I clicks on these buttons to open the popup (Used `<p:dialog>`), it opens but methods in `calenderBean` are executed, though the bean is not used for the popups.
It delays the process further.

How can I manage this as clicking on the buttons will not invoke the `calenderBean` and its methods.
Please suggest!

Comment: I guess clicking on button is invoking PhaseListener as part of its lifecycle. And you have some code in PhaseListener which is calling method of `calenderBean`. Paste code for your xhtml, bean and PhaseListener.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Process and PartialSubmit from primefaces to control what you sent in your commandbutton like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="YourText" update="componentToUpdate" partialSubmit="true" process="nameOfComponentYouNeedToSend" />
```

See more in: 
[Partial Submit](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/partialSubmit.xhtml)

[Partial Processing](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/process.xhtml)

PS: in the process you can use generics like '@this', '@form', '@none' and others.

PS2: In the next question please put some code or specific better becouse like BalusC said it's too ambiguos.

Comment: @aledpardo: if you take so many effort to only "improve link formatting", **please** also take effort to verify and fix those links! Those PrimeFaces showcase links in several posts you merely edited for the points are namely broken since PrimeFaces showcase upgrade to 5.0.